# For which values this integral converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

This question is realy hard for me and I'd like to get some advises:

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
     x^{\alpha}(1-\cos(1-x))^{\beta} &  x\in (0,1)\\[6px]
    \dfrac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}  &   x\ge 1
  \end{cases}$$

I need to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that make $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converge.

Now I think I need to split the integral to $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ and 
$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and check the converge for each integral. But I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Potential issues are as $x \to 0^+$, as $x \to 1^-$ and as $x \to \infty.$

- As $x \to 0^+$, one has $$
     f(x)=x^\alpha(1-\cos1)^\beta+O(x^{\alpha+1}) $$ and $ \displaystyle
     \int_0^\epsilon\!\!f(x)dx$ converges ($0<\epsilon<1$) iff $ \displaystyle
     \int_0^\epsilon\!\!x^\alpha dx$ converges, that is it converges only for
  $\alpha>-1.$
- As $x \to 1^-$, one has $$
     f(x)=(1-x)^{2\beta}2^{-\beta}+O((x-1)^{2\beta+1}) $$ and $ \displaystyle
     \int_{1-\epsilon}^1\!\!f(x)dx$ converges iff $ \displaystyle
     \int_{1-\epsilon}^1\!\!(1-x)^{2\beta} dx$ converges, that is it converges only for
  $\beta>-1/2.$
- As $x \to \infty$, one has $$
     f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\max(\alpha,\beta)}}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{\max(\alpha,\beta)+(\max(\alpha,\beta)-\min(\alpha,\beta))}}\right)
     $$ and $ \displaystyle \int_1^\infty\!\!f(x)dx$ converges iff $
     \displaystyle \int_0^1\!\!\frac{1}{x^{\max(\alpha,\beta)}} dx$
  converges, that is it converges only for $\max(\alpha,\beta)>1.$

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. I need to use the comparison test for each problematic point(0, 1, infinity)?

Comment: @Mat The answer is yes. You are welcome!