# How to find all values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\int _0^{\infty }f\left(x\right)$ converge

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{\alpha }\left(1-cos\left(1-x\right)\right)^{\beta } & \text{if $\;\;\;0<x<1$} \\ \frac{1}{x^{\alpha }+x^{\beta }} & \text{if $\;\;\;1\ge x$} \end{cases}$

I split into two integrals:

$\int _0^1x^{\alpha }\left(1-cos\left(1-x\right)\right)^{\beta }dx\:+\:\int _1^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha }+x^{\beta }}\right)dx$

I want to use the comparison test. but I find it hard to choose $g(x)$ that will give me an answer for $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Answer (score 0):

The convergence is obtained for

> $$
> \alpha>-1 \quad \text{and} \quad \beta>-1/2 \quad \text{and} \quad \max(\alpha,\beta)>1.
> $$

**Hint**. Potential issues are as $x \to 0^+$, as $x \to 1^-$ and as $x \to \infty.$

- As $x \to 0^+$, one has $$
     f(x)=x^\alpha(1-\cos1)^\beta+O(x^{\alpha+1}) $$ and $ \displaystyle
     \int_0^\epsilon\!\!f(x)dx$ converges ($0<\epsilon<1$) iff $ \displaystyle
     \int_0^\epsilon\!\!x^\alpha dx$ converges, that is it converges iff $\alpha>-1.$
- As $x \to 1^-$, one has $$
     f(x)=(1-x)^{2\beta}2^{-\beta}+O((x-1)^{2\beta+1}) $$ and $ \displaystyle
     \int_{1-\epsilon}^1\!\!f(x)dx$ converges ($0<\epsilon<1$) iff $ \displaystyle
     \int_{1-\epsilon}^1\!\!(1-x)^{2\beta} dx$ converges, that is it converges iff
  $\beta>-1/2.$
- As $x \to \infty$, one has $$
     f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\max(\alpha,\beta)}}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{\max(\alpha,\beta)+(\max(\alpha,\beta)-\min(\alpha,\beta))}}\right)
     $$ and $ \displaystyle \int_1^\infty\!\!f(x)dx$ converges iff $
     \displaystyle \int_0^1\!\!\frac{1}{x^{\max(\alpha,\beta)}} dx$
  converges, that is it converges iff $\max(\alpha,\beta)>1.$

Comment: It's a duplicate and you knew it: you answered the same question yesterday, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1747724/62967

Comment: I didn't learn yet the O notation . maybe that's a series ? I didn't got to it yet. I need to you comparison tests

Comment: @egreg someone postes this question ?  this specific one ?

Comment: @idandi Yes, look at the link below your question

Comment: @egreg What are the odds ? what should I do ?

Comment: @idandi Nothing; just read the same answer in the other thread. Don't worry, I remembered the other question because I happened to edit it. It's not easy to see whether a question has already been asked, so there's nothing wrong on your side.

Comment: I dont understand the answer since I didn't get to series yet. and I beleive that O(something) is a series.
thanks.

Comment: @Olivier,  What is the "O" notation stands for ?

Comment: @idandi A function $f$ is said to be $O(g)$ near un certain value $a$ if there exists a constant $C$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$ in a neighbourhood of $a$. In other words, if $f$ is 'dominated' by $g$ near $a$. Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I understand,but what function should I choose at the comparison test ?
should I devide the original function with $f(x)=(1-x)^{2\beta}$ ?  maybe I just didn't get to this part at my learning yet.

Comment: When one writes $\displaystyle f(x)=(1-x)^{2\beta}2^{-\beta}+O((x-1)^{2\beta+1}) $, it means that we can neglect all the series compared with the $O$ term in a neighbourhood of $1$. May be you have not seen it in your course yet.